# Mobile Image Upload with Processing first?

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile-website

When I upload an image from a mobile device you have two options:

1. reduce the size on the device and upload the result
2. upload the full image and reduce the size on the server

**Which one is better?**

Answer (score 1):

For the user experience, it is better to do all the work you can server-side, minimising the processing time and the transfer time.

I would recommend doing all the work on image on the server if you want the application to be fast, and if the transformation make the image heavier.

Now you may have problem in the future if you have mutliple upload in the same time with a low performance server. If it is the case, choose to do the work on device to devide the work on each device.

Comment: Since the download can be done as a background task I too think that doing the resizing on the server would be best.

Comment: But what if the image size will be reduced by the processing. Usually the bandwidth of the network is a problem on mobile so this might make the upload faster.

Comment: If the image size is reduce, and you think you will have a lot a upload in the same time asking too much processing for your server, do the process on device then upload. If the transformation is less than 5sec it should be ok for the user experience.

Comment: If it help you, don't forget to validate and maybe up-vote, thanks you !

Comment: I just see you didn't validate. Please validate if it help you and vote up :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think The "1" is best,because This way of consuming less flow;this option is very important for android app

Answer (score 0):

I always use the 1st approach. You never know how fast your user's internet is, so I prefer doing it locally and save time on the upload.
That is specially true in 3d world countries where 3G speeds are generally very slow and unreliable.